# Implicit conversion warning in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, object, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

The first, my code as below:

```
    Dim eventType As Object = Nothing

    eventType = GetEventType()

    If Not (eventType Is Nothing) Then

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassSelectEvents Then
            m_selectEvents = eventType  ' Warning BC 42016: Implicit type conversion from 'Object' to 'ClassSelectEvents'.
        End If

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassMouseEvents Then
            m_mouseEvents = eventType   ' Warning BC 42016: Implicit type conversion from 'Object' to 'ClassMouseEvents'.
        End If

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassTriadEvents Then
            m_triadEvents = eventType   ' Warning BC 42016: Implicit type conversion from 'Object' to 'ClassTriadEvents'.
        End If

    End If
```

Because of the warning display after the compiler, I modified it as shown below but still displayed a warning.

At the second If statement, i think type of `eventType` is `Object`. Is that different? My code where is wrong Please tell me how hide warnings ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim eventType As Object = Nothing

    eventType = GetEventType()

    If Not (eventType Is Nothing) Then

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassSelectEvents Then
            'm_selectEvents = eventType
            'm_selectEvents = TryCast(eventType, ClassSelectEvents)
            m_selectEvents = DirectCast(eventType, ClassSelectEvents)
        End If

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassMouseEvents Then
            'm_mouseEvents = eventType
            'm_selectEvents = TryCast(eventType, ClassMouseEvents)  ' Warning BC42016: Implicit type conversion from 'ClassMouseEvents' to 'ClassSelectEvents'.
            m_selectEvents = DirectCast(eventType, ClassMouseEvents)    ' Warning BC42016: Implicit type conversion from 'ClassMouseEvents' to 'ClassSelectEvents'.
        End If

        If TypeOf eventType Is ClassTriadEvents Then
            'm_triadEvents = eventType
            'm_selectEvents = TryCast(eventType, ClassTriadEvents)  ' Warning BC42016: Implicit type conversion from 'ClassTriadEvents' to 'ClassSelectEvents'.
            m_selectEvents = DirectCast(eventType, ClassTriadEvents)    ' Warning BC42016: Implicit type conversion from 'ClassTriadEvents' to 'ClassSelectEvents'.
        End If

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to `m_selectEvents` in all three `If` blocks when the last two should be `m_mouseEvents` and `m_triadEvents`.

By the way, there's no point using `TryCast` there because your `If` statement has already guaranteed that the cast will work.  You should just use `DirectCast`.  If you wanted to use `TryCast` then you'd do it like this:

```
m_selectEvents = TryCast(eventType, ClassSelectEvents)

If m_selectEvents Is Nothing Then
    m_mouseEvents = DirectCast(eventType, ClassMouseEvents)

    If m_mouseEvents Is Nothing Then
        m_triadEvents = DirectCast(eventType, ClassTriadEvents)
    End If
End If
```

`TryCast` will return `Nothing` if the cast fails so you test for `Nothing` after trying to cast.  If you're not testing for `Nothing` after using `TryCast` then you almost certainly shouldn't be using `TryCast` to begin with.
 EDIT: Hmmm... I see that you changed `TryCast` to `DirectCast` after/while I posted my answer. Hopefully my explanation helped some anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your very clean and easy-to-understand answer.
I'm not a VB.Net developer. I've literally just started skimming the code an hour and a half ago.
So, I don't know the differences between TryCast, Ctype, DirectCast. I'm looking into it now.